React Vite Error on Production Build: "jsxs" is not exported by "node_modules/react/jsx-runtime.js
I am using React + Javascript + Vite for the project. I installed the required packages for the project , Also i install one package from  local npm installation eg
npm install source_folder 

The local package which is a component library , after this installation i import the component and npm run dev  is working fine. But
npm run build 

failing with below error
✓ 34 modules transformed.
x Build failed in 751ms
error during build:
src/App.jsx (3:9): "Button" is not exported by "../../BCL-UI/dist/index.js", imported by "src/App.jsx".
file: /Users/user1/workspace/projects/poc/chat-app/src/App.jsx:3:9

here BCL-UI is the local package installed, Below is the vite configuration
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['bcl-ui'],
  },
})

package.json below
  "dependencies": {
    "axl-ui": "file:../../BCL-UI",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },

Note : Only the npm run build is failed and npm run dev is working fine
